# Printing elements stored in hash of a hash

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hash-of-hashes

```
final HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>> teams;
   teams= new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>>();


    teams.put(1,new HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>(){{
        put(2,new Integer[] { 1,0});}}); 
        System.out.println(teams.get(1).get(2));
```

I am trying to implement hash of hashes in java. I need to print integer array being stored in hash of a hash. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: How would you print an `Integer[]` if it were not stored in a hash of hashes? Do the same thing at the appropriate place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct (I only re-indented here), and I added the call to the [Arrays.toString](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2009/10/print-array-content-with-arraystostring.html) method in your println call.

```
final HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>> teams;
teams = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>>();

teams.put(1, new HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>() {
  {
    put(2, new Integer[] { 1, 0 });
  }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teams.get(1).get(2)));
```

Comment: Hint: You are much more likely to get upvotes, if you add just one paragraph or explanation, and possibly some comments to the code.

Comment: @hyde I added the sentence above. OP was only missing Arrays.toString

Answer (score 0):

Note:  code  `teams.get(1).get(2)` returns type of Integer[].

`teams.get(1)` will get a HashMap, in the example, its key is 2 and its value is an Integer Array (Integer[]) with elements [1,0]

`teams.get(1).get(2)` returns values, whose type is `Integer[]`.

You *CAN NOT* print its value via  `System.out.println(teams.get(1).get(2))` directly because toString is not implemented.

There are 2 ways for you to print the element in array as follows:

1 you can print element in array using its index,

like

```
     System.out.println(teams.get(1).get(2)[0]);//print 1
     System.out.println(teams.get(1).get(2)[1]);//Print 0
```

OR

2 Use `Arrays.toString` menthod to print all the elements in array,

like

```
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teams.get(1).get(2)));//Print [1,0]
```